# I am not able to get the changed state on touch event handler in my component. Neither through usestate or reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a very weird issue. I am using touch event handlers for swipe. So for that, I need to use the state to get previous touched position. The state change is visible on the mouse events but I am not able to get the changed state either through useState or the reducers on mobile devices.

I dispatch action to update the state in `handleStart`. This updates the state and I can see the changed state through Redux Devtools. On Desktop, I can see the changed state in `handleMove` but cannot see it on mobile devices.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import classes from './SingleCard.module.scss';
import * as quizBuilderActions from '../../../store/actions/index'

export const SingleCard = (props) => {
  
  const singleCardRef = useRef(null);

  const [xgClass, setXgClass] = useState([classes.Graphic]);
  const [bottomText, setBottomText] = useState('Lipsum');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  /*
  const [swipeState, setSwipeState] = useState(
        {
          left: 0,
          originalOffset: 0,
          velocity: 0,
          timeOfLastDragEvent: 0,
          touchStartX: 0,
          prevTouchX: 0,
          beingTouched: false,
          height: 0,
          intervalId: null
        }
    );
  */

  const swipeState = useSelector(state => {
        return state.quizBuilder.swipeState;
    });

  
  useEffect(() => {

    switch(props.cardname){
        case '1G':
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic1G]);
            setBottomText('Lipsum');
            break;
        case '2G':
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic2G]);
            setBottomText('Lipsum');
            break;
        case '3G':
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic3G]);
            setBottomText('Lipsum');
            break;
        case '4G':
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic4G]);
            setBottomText('Lipsum');
            break;
        case '5G':
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic5G]);
            setBottomText('mmWave');
            break;
        default:
            setXgClass([classes.Graphic, classes.Graphic5G]);
            setBottomText('mmWave');
            break;
    }

    singleCardRef.current.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStartEvent => {
            handleTouchStart(touchStartEvent);
          }, { passive: false });

        singleCardRef.current.addEventListener('touchmove',  touchMoveEvent => {
            handleTouchMove(touchMoveEvent);
          }, { passive: false });

        singleCardRef.current.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
            handleTouchEnd();
          }, { passive: false });
        

    dispatch(quizBuilderActions.updateSwipe({
          left: 0,
          originalOffset: 0,
          velocity: 0,
          timeOfLastDragEvent: 0,
          touchStartX: 0,
          prevTouchX: 0,
          beingTouched: false,
          height: 110,
          intervalId: null
        }));


  },[props.cardname, singleCardRef.current]);
  const getNextCard = (isNext)=> {
    let nextCard = false;

    if(isNext)
    {
        switch (props.cardname)
        {
            case '1G':
                nextCard = '2G';
                break;
            case '2G':
                nextCard = '3G';
                break;
            case '3G':
                nextCard = '4G';
                break;
            case '4G':
                nextCard = '5G';
                break;
            case '5G':
                nextCard = '1G';
                break;
            default:
                nextCard = '1G';
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch (props.cardname)
        {
            case '1G':
                nextCard = '5G';
                break;
            case '2G':
                nextCard = '1G';
                break;
            case '3G':
                nextCard = '2G';
                break;
            case '4G':
                nextCard = '3G';
                break;
            case '5G':
                nextCard = '4G';
                break;
            default:
                nextCard = '1G';
                break;
        }
    }

    return nextCard;

  };

  const handleRemoveSelf = (isNext) => {
    dispatch(quizBuilderActions.updateSwipe({
                ...swipeState,
                left: 0
        }
    ));

    window.setTimeout(() => props.onSwipe(getNextCard(isNext)), 250);
  }

  const handleStart = (clientX) => {
    
    if (swipeState.intervalId !== null) {
      window.clearInterval(swipeState.intervalId);
    }

    touchStart = clientX;

// dispatching action to record the initial touch location. This gets triggered.

    dispatch(quizBuilderActions.updateSwipe({
      ...swipeState,    
      timeOfLastDragEvent: Date.now(),
      touchStartX: clientX,
      beingTouched: true,
      intervalId: null
    }));

  };
  
  const handleMove = (clientX) => {

    // On Desktop, swipestate gives the recorded state values that was dispatched from handleStart.

// On Mobile(and emulator), swipestate does not give the state values dispatched from handleStart.But on Redux Devtools, I can see its updated.

    if (swipeState.beingTouched) {

// I Cannot reach here in mobile devices. 

      const touchX = clientX;
      const currTime = Date.now();
      const elapsed = currTime - swipeState.timeOfLastDragEvent;
      const velocity = 20 * (touchX - swipeState.prevTouchX) / elapsed;
      let deltaX = touchX - swipeState.touchStartX + swipeState.originalOffset;
      
      if (deltaX < -150) {
        handleRemoveSelf(true);
      } else if (deltaX > 150) {
        handleRemoveSelf(false);
      }

      dispatch(quizBuilderActions.updateSwipe({
        ...swipeState,
        left: deltaX,
        velocity,
        timeOfLastDragEvent: currTime,
        prevTouchX: touchX
      }));
    }
  }
 
  const handleEnd = () => {
    dispatch(quizBuilderActions.updateSwipe({
      ...swipeState,    
      touchStartX: 0,
      beingTouched: false,
      intervalId: window.setInterval(animateSlidingToZero(), 33)
    }));
  }
  
  const handleTouchStart = (touchStartEvent) => {
    touchStartEvent.preventDefault();
    handleStart(touchStartEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX);
  }
  
  const handleTouchMove = (touchMoveEvent) => {
    handleMotion(touchMoveEvent.targetTouches[0].clientX);
  }
  
  const handleTouchEnd = () => {
    handleEnd();
  }
  
  const handleMouseDown  = (mouseDownEvent) => {
    mouseDownEvent.preventDefault();
    handleStart(mouseDownEvent.clientX);
  }
  
  const handleMouseMove = (mouseMoveEvent) => {
    handleMove(mouseMoveEvent.clientX);
  }
  
  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    handleEnd();
  }
  
  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    handleMouseUp();
  }
  
    


  return (
    <div 
        className={classes.SingleCard}
        ref={singleCardRef}
        //onTouchStart={touchStartEvent => handleTouchStart(touchStartEvent)}
        //onTouchMove={touchMoveEvent => handleTouchMove(touchMoveEvent)}
        //onTouchEnd={() => handleTouchEnd()}
        // The following event handlers are for mouse compatibility:
        onMouseDown={mouseDownEvent => handleMouseDown(mouseDownEvent)}
        onMouseMove={mouseMoveEvent => handleMouseMove(mouseMoveEvent)}
        onMouseUp={() => handleMouseUp()}
        onMouseLeave={() => handleMouseLeave()}
    >
        <div 
            className={classes.InnerBox}
            style={
                {
                    left: swipeState.left
                }
            }
        >
            <h2>{props.cardname}</h2>
            <div className={xgClass.join(' ')}></div>
            <h3>{bottomText}</h3>
            <h4>2020</h4>
            <p>{swipeState.beingTouched ? 'Touched' : 'Not Touched'}</p>
         </div> 
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleCard;
```

Comment: You have added all the event handlers for  mouse events. Mouse events do not exist in mobile devices.

Comment: You will have to use the touch events that you have commented in your code. :-)

Comment: Thank You @devd, I needed to use react built in SyntheticEvent.